# Looping through files pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the code that I obtained from: [Comparing and replacing values inside DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304883/comparing-and-replacing-values-inside-dataframes)

```
main_df = pd.read_csv('main.txt', sep='|', encoding='utf-8')
data_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='utf-8')

main_df_part = main_df[['PRIM_LAT_DEC', 'PRIM_LONG_DEC', 'FEATURE_NAME', 'STATE_ALPHA']]
main_df_part.columns = ['LAT', 'LONG', 'CITY', 'STATE']
main_df_part = main_df_part.set_index(['CITY', 'STATE'])
data_df = data_df.set_index(['CITY', 'STATE'])

data_df.update(main_df_part)

data_df.to_csv('data/new.csv', sep=',', mode='a')
```

I have about 60 files that I need to run through. `main_df`, I tried the following:

**In summary**

1. Concatnate the files, but kept getting `pandas.parser.CParserError:
   Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory`.
2. Using chunksize, but this converts the DataFrame into
   `pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader` making some of the methods I used
   invalid
3. Lastly I tried iterating through each file and placing the correct
   name instead of `main.txt` but kept getting `Exception: cannot
   handle a non-unique multi-index!` when doing so.

This is using the third method:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('./data') if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('./data', f))]

for w in files:
    main_df = pd.read_csv(w, sep='|', low_memory=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Any ideas how to fix the multi-index error?

**Expanded information**

**Error from method 1:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Leb/Desktop/Python/py-script/geo_pandas.py", line 6, in <module>
    main_df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='|', low_memory=False, encoding='utf-8')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 474, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 260, in _read
    return parser.read()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 721, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1170, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 772, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:7581)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 858, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:8532)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1742, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:20715)
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory
```

**Error from method 2:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Leb/Desktop/Python/py-script/geo_pandas.py", line 11, in <module>
    main_df_part = main_df[['PRIM_LAT_DEC', 'PRIM_LONG_DEC','FEATURE_NAME', 'STATE_ALPHA']]
TypeError: 'TextFileReader' object is not subscriptable
```

**Error from method 3:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Leb/Desktop/Python/py-script/geo_pandas.py", line 32, in <module>
    data_df.update(main_df_part)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3416, in update
    other = other.reindex_like(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1564, in reindex_like
    return self.reindex(**d)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2511, in reindex
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1773, in reindex
    method, fill_value, copy).__finalize__(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2470, in _reindex_axes
    fill_value, limit)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2477, in _reindex_index
    limit=limit)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 4929, in reindex
    "cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!")
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

Comment: Kindly post the exact traceback for each item you've tried.

Comment: Will take a second, but I'll work on it.

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess for Method 3: `main_df_part` has two indices which are exactly the same. Scan it through. It's possible that you have a city-state combination that's showing up more than once in one of your files.

Comment: You're referring to `main.txt` (60 files) correct? Would that also be an issue for `data.csv`?

Comment: Yes, `main.txt`. When updating your dataframe using another dataframe, the latter should have unique indices. Otherwise, if you have duplicates, `pandas` would throw an error because it will be confused as to which index-value to use. The reverse, I think, might be true, though I have no way to check right now.

Comment: I really thought I tried it for one of the files and it worked fine. It's gonna be fun trying to delete those duplicate. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The code is sound, to be honest. I'd do it this way as well. One possible way I'd do this is to add a check if the unique values of the index is same as the length of the dataframe. If not, print out the name plus some warning. Else, just export the updated dataframe to CSV.

Comment: I'll look into that, quite new to pandas. Seems better than having to edit 60 files.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments, it's possible that one of the files you're using to update `data.csv` has duplicates in its index. I ran a sample code below. It's quite lengthy but I hope it shows this particular case.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: main = pd.read_csv('Main.csv')
   ...: target1 = pd.read_csv('Target1.csv')
   ...: target2 = pd.read_csv('Target2.csv')

In [3]: main
Out[3]: 
          City State  Lat  Long
0           NY    NY  NaN   NaN
1       Albany    NY  NaN   NaN
2     Syracuse    NY  NaN   NaN
3     Columbia    MO  NaN   NaN
4  Kansas City    MO  NaN   NaN
5  Springfield    MO  NaN   NaN

In [4]: target1
Out[4]: 
   Lat  Long      City State
0  100   200        NY    NY
1  300   400    Albany    NY
2  500   600  Syracuse    NY

In [5]: target2
Out[5]: 
   Lat  Long         City State
0  100   200     Columbia    MO
1  300   400  Kansas City    MO
2  500   600  Springfield    MO
3  700   800  Springfield    MO

In [6]: m = main.set_index(['City','State'])
   ...: t1 = target1.set_index(['City','State'])
   ...: t2 = target2.set_index(['City','State'])

In [7]: m
Out[7]: 
                   Lat  Long
City        State           
NY          NY     NaN   NaN
Albany      NY     NaN   NaN
Syracuse    NY     NaN   NaN
Columbia    MO     NaN   NaN
Kansas City MO     NaN   NaN
Springfield MO     NaN   NaN

In [8]: t1
Out[8]: 
                Lat  Long
City     State           
NY       NY     100   200
Albany   NY     300   400
Syracuse NY     500   600

In [9]: t2
Out[9]: 
                   Lat  Long
City        State           
Columbia    MO     100   200
Kansas City MO     300   400
Springfield MO     500   600
            MO     700   800
```

Pay particular attention the the last line above, `[9]`. Note how `Springfield` now assigns two rows of values to itself.

```
In [12]: m.update(t1)

In [13]: m
Out[13]: 
                   Lat  Long
City        State           
NY          NY     100   200
Albany      NY     300   400
Syracuse    NY     500   600
Columbia    MO     NaN   NaN
Kansas City MO     NaN   NaN
Springfield MO     NaN   NaN

In [14]: m.update(t2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-f5f30165a245> in <module>()
----> 1 m.update(t2)

C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in update(self, other, join, overwrite, filter_func, raise_conflict)
   3414             other = DataFrame(other)
   3415 
-> 3416         other = other.reindex_like(self)
   3417 
   3418         for col in self.columns:

C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in reindex_like(self, other, method, copy, limit)
   1562                 method=method, copy=copy, limit=limit)
   1563 
-> 1564         return self.reindex(**d)
   1565 
   1566     def drop(self, labels, axis=0, level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise'):

C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in reindex(self, index, columns, **kwargs)
   2509     def reindex(self, index=None, columns=None, **kwargs):
   2510         return super(DataFrame, self).reindex(index=index, columns=columns,
-> 2511                                               **kwargs)
   2512 
   2513     @Appender(_shared_docs['reindex_axis'] % _shared_doc_kwargs)

C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1771         # perform the reindex on the axes
   1772         return self._reindex_axes(axes, level, limit,
-> 1773                                   method, fill_value, copy).__finalize__(self)
   1774 
   1775     def _reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, method, fill_value, copy):

C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, method, fill_value, copy)
   2468         if index is not None:
   2469             frame = frame._reindex_index(index, method, copy, level,
-> 2470                                          fill_value, limit)
   2471 
   2472         return frame

C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _reindex_index(self, new_index, method, copy, level, fill_value, limit)
   2475                        limit=None):
   2476         new_index, indexer = self.index.reindex(new_index, method, level,
-> 2477                                                 limit=limit)
   2478         return self._reindex_with_indexers({0: [new_index, indexer]},
   2479                                            copy=copy, fill_value=fill_value,

C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.pyc in reindex(self, target, method, level, limit)
   4927                 else:
   4928                     raise Exception(
-> 4929                         "cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!")
   4930 
   4931         if not isinstance(target, MultiIndex):

Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

This throws the same error as yours.

Comment: I am considering using `drop_duplicates` as a solution to get rid of the extra row. Until I get a better set of `main.txt` I'll just have to go with what I got. That is before assigning indices.